# Como converter de Hexadecimal para binario

Tags: c, hexadecimal

Bom na verdade eu consegui na força bruta queria saber, existe outra maneira de fazer matematicamente meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char numero[1000],aux[10000];
  scanf("%s", numero);
  for(int i = 0; i < numero[i] && numero[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if(numero[i] == '0')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0000");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '1')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0001");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '2')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0010");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '3')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0011");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '4')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0100");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '5')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0101");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '6')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0110");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '7')
    {
        strcat(aux,"0111");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '8')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1000");
    }
    else if(numero[i] == '9')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1001");
    }
    else if((numero[i] == 'A')||(numero[i])=='a')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1010");
    }
    else if((numero[i] == 'B')||(numero[i])=='b')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1011");
    }
    else if((numero[i] == 'C')||(numero[i])=='c')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1100");
    }
    else if((numero[i] == 'D')||(numero[i])=='d')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1101");
    }
    else if((numero[i] == 'E')||(numero[i])=='e')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1110");
    }
    else if((numero[i] == 'F')||(numero[i])=='f')
    {
        strcat(aux,"1111");
    }
  }
   puts(aux);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mas não entendi alguma coisas no seu código.. o porque do laço for, o porque de as arrays terem tanto espaço. Ao meu ver tem 2 problemas no seu código: 1 - o laço for é quebrado se algum dos números for diferente de '\0', o ideal não seria um continue? e outro problema é, em vez de utilizar else if, utilize switch case.

Comment: Você poderia declarar um ```int int_var;``` e depois usar ```scanf('%x', &int_var)```, dessa forma você já pode converter de hexa diretamente para um inteiro.